# javascript if statement triggering on false condition

Tags: javascript

The image linked below is a screen grab from debugging some JS (in Chrome v86). It shows the JS code & the current state of the variables in question.

Can someone shed some light on why 'updatePosition()' be being called, despite the 'if' statement's condition clearly evaluating to false..?

[screen grab, as described above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJHkH.png)

cheers

Paul

Comment: Check if tmp is false and not "false"

Comment: i did...its not. Also isTracking & isSlewing are both boolean

Answer (score 2):

From that screenshot, your value of `tmp` is a string of `"false"` rather than a boolean of false so it is actually a truthy value.

Comment: That would only be true if isTracking & isSlewing were both Strings. However, they are both boolean. Infact, the example in the screen grab, 'isTracking' was true &  'isSlewing' was false. Since the exprssion (!isTracking || isSlewing) therefore evaluates to a boolean, 'tmp' is also boolean, so the if statement should not have triggered...

Comment: @ubercoder but the screenshot you provided with the breakpoint is showing `tmp = "false" ` ... in that case, `tmp` is _not_ a boolean and a string of `"false"`  .  If it were `tmp = false`, then you'd have a boolean